# Наследуемые метки

Tags: предложение, метки

##### Описание

К примеру, я не знаю js и не хочу у себя видеть вопросы связанные с ними. Я нажимаю игнорировать [js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js). Потом я вижу у себя метку [jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). Я как человек не интересующийся js скрываю и его, потом [react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react)...
И вот прошло уже час, я вроде скрыл все метки связанные с [js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js). Но вот незадача: есть ещё фреймворк какой-нибудь [кирпич-js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%87-js) о котором я не знал и так же у него есть подметки [кирпич-js-ui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%87-js-ui), [кирпич-js-2d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%87-js-2d), ...
Так же никто не отменил что потом метки к js добавят.
Вот почему я предлагаю сделать наследуемые метки. То есть, в начале у нас есть [js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js), потом есть [react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) который наследуется от [js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js). И вот я скрываю метку [js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) и всё связанные с ним пропадает. Или же скрываю только [кирпич-js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%87-js) и уже его подветвь пропадает.

##### Вопрос

Может есть на сайте уже какое-то решение данной проблемы, но я пока о нем не знаю. Что думаете насчет мысли?

Comment: а если мне не интересен js сам по себе но интересен реакт, то что? или обожаю jquery хлебом не корми, то что?

Comment: более того - jquery и просто js вообще могут быть не связаны никак абсолютно

Comment: Проще пойти от обратного: если всё так плачевно, подписаться только на те метки, которые интересуют.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В таком случае мы игнорируем [tag:js] и подписываемся на [tag:jquery]. Система видит что [tag:js] "плохой" - скрывает эту ветвь, но дальше видит что [tag:jquery] "хороший" и показывает только эту ветвь из js... `подписаться только на те метки, которые интересуют.` - на данный момент я так и делаю, но подписка не скрывает нежелательное, а подсвечивает то что отмечено.

Comment: Проблема в вашем подходе с js и jquery в том, что игнор js условино скрывает и 50 зависимых меток и тогда, если меня интересует 47 из них, то мне надо будет 47 добавлять в избранное. Короч поменяем шило на мыло.....

Comment: "подписка не скрывает нежелательное, а подсвечивает то что отмечено"  --- вполне достаточно. Думаю больше рациональное решение это задать в настройках "скрывать всё, что не в «избранном»"  (а пока на это можно временно сделать небольшой юзерскрипт)

Comment: не стоит также забывать, что если реализовывать наследование меток, то это может начать вылазить и в других местах и вреда от этого будет гораздо больше.

Comment: также Вы не учитываете то, что метки являются пользовательским контентом... т.е. эти записи могут создаваться любым пользователем с репутацией чуть выше нуля... Из этого следует, что и дерево меток строить нужно будет самим пользователям. И вводя наследование мы сломаем выстроенный процесс. Также придется вводить новые очереди проверок, придумывать новые знаки чтобы мотивировать пользователей устанавливать связи, помимо этого будут новые привелегии и необходимо будет добавить кучу новых проверок.

Comment: В итоге, как мне видится, профит от всего этого мероприятия неочевидный, а проблем связанных с ним - не оберешься. И овчинка выделки не будет стоить. Мы уже два года не можем уговорить разработчиков ключи для `About` поменять, а тут такое...

Comment: Мысль отличная, но писать нужно на https://meta.stackexchange.com/; здесь никто слушать не будет. Хотя там тоже вряд ли будут, компания очень не любит делать новые фичи по заказу.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Может быть конкретно `jquery` не надо наследовать от `js`, но есть метки, в которых сообщество уже договорилось делать такое "наследование" руками (`c++-xx` от `c++`, из того, что знаю). В принципе у нас уже есть автоматическая голосовалка за синонимы тегов, можно было бы сделать подобную для наследования...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вот видите, вы думаете что jquery не надо наследовать, а вот автор считает. Так что при условии что такая фича будет одним угодят, другие будут ущемлены. Да и получается надо будет голосовать по всяким меткам по синонимизации (сейчас напомню итого 5832 меток, да не по всем надо, но тем не менее). ... Но и опять с версиями языка ок, а вот с этими фреймворками, Cms и пр. как быть? Это точно не синонимы............В общем, как я писал выше - проще сделать галочку "показывать только отслеживаемые метки"

Comment: Я не вижу никакой разницы с ручным приписыванием `c++` ко всем вопросам с `c++-??`, тут тоже ущемлены те, кому это не нравится. Если мнения разделятся, на мете делается голосовалка, как по любому другому вопросу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat и какой смысл, чтобы поменять ущемлённых с одних на других?))) Звучит бредово)) А приписывание например к метке с фреймворком его языка, типа django-python  выглядит немного, извините за выражение, имбицильно. Как будто человек итак не знает что это за фреймворк и для чего. Более того выглядит это искорёженно, т.к. всё таки называется он django... Возникает также проблема, если фреймворк уже содержит в названии ЯП,  получается vueJs-js будет выглядеть совсем нелепо

Comment: Меня это интересует в первую очередь для тех тегов, где сейчас уже происходит ровно то же самое, но тег ставят руками другие пользователи. За JS с его 100500 фреймворков - не знаю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен с Алексеем в этом вопросе. Я не вижу варианта реализовать данный функционал без каких-бы то ни было проблем. Тут придется очень сильно натягивать сову на глобус и делать миллион допущений, что не самая лучшая идея.... и да...в конкретно Вашем случае это более чем оправданно, но это невозможно сказать о других метках...поэтому я могу лишь искренне посочувствовать Вам... Это реалии `c++`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat по поводу c++ c++11 c++12 c++13 c++14 и т.д. - На этом ресурсе давно есть wildcard и я сам им пользуюсь,  достаточно в игнорируемые написать `c++*`  и тогда будут игнорироваться метки, которые начинаются на "c++" и дальше в названии "что угодно"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Для себя у меня конечно уже все настроено (правда списком, а не wildcard-ом). Тут проблема в том, что *другие* пользователи могут не увидеть вопрос, если у них только `c++` в тегах.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский автор не считает что прям именно [tag:jquery] нужно наследовать именно от [tag:js]. Это всего лишь пример, может быть не очень удачный. Этим я просто хотел описать работоспособность этой конструкции.

Comment: @Арман не важно. Проблем с этим будет очень достаточно, как мы уже описали это всё в комментариях и более простое решение тоже